# Unable to create Cross-Platform .NET Standard Plugin Templates project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to develop my own plugins in xamarin form. I installed **Cross-Platform .NET Standard Plugin Templates** in VS 2019. I can see in description **Cross-Platform .NET Standard Plugin Templates** works with 2017 and 2019. 
When I try to create new project it keeps going on saying creating project.

[image: VS 2019 keep going on saying creating project]

When I look in the directory, I can see some files being generated.

[image: File generated in project directory]

Comment: What is the version of visual-studio 2019? I use Visual-studio 2019 16.0.3 can reproduce your issue, now I want to update my Visual-studio 2019, but it need some time, so you can try.

Comment: I update visual-studio 2019 to latest version, but this issue still exist, so you can report this issue by clicking **Help-send feedback-report a problem** in Visual-studio 2019, then Ms will see it and try to fix this, I will also to report this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's an existing issue with VS2019

> Creating a new Project with VS2019 shows missing references / they cant be loaded. Appeared after last VS Update.

If you wait long enough you can do the following :

> Note- after last VS 2019 update- edit the csproj file and update the MSBuild.Sdk.Extras to version 2.0.54 so all dependencies load and the project will build.

**UPDATE:**

Had to download Visual studio 2017 to create the project

Comment: The problem is, it does not create a full project. It just keep saying creating and later shows not responding.

Comment: @KhimBahadurGurung , made an update to my answer, at the end I downloaded visual studio 2017 which worked perfectly, from there you can open it with 2019